# how to pass chid function return as return of parent function

Tags: javascript

```
        function myValidationAction2(fieldValue){       
        var c=fieldValue;
         var d1;

        function foo(callback)
        {   
            var abc=null;

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // DETECT ALL BROWSER RATHER THEN IE 
            {
                abc=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if(window.ActiveXObject) // DETECT IE
            {
                abc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            // SEND REQUEST TO SERVER
            abc.open("GET","ajax4.php?txt_email="+c);


            abc.send();
            abc.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if(abc.readyState==4)
                {


                    callback($(abc.responseText).text());


                }


            }

        };

        foo(function(result)
        {
            //here result is display Successfully.
            //i want to pass result as return of function parent function myValidationAction2.....
        });


    }
```

in short i want to give return true or false which was come in abc.responsetext as a first time function is executed.So i use callbcak to foo function which is called as foo(function(result)); the result was successfull comed in function but i not want to modify the result instead i want to return result as a return of parent function.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var a=myValidationAction21("hello");//but what if it is callback function how to get return value in variable a
          
    alert("a="+a);
  });
  
  function myValidationAction21(fieldValue,callback) { // callback arg. here!!
 alert("i am execit");
 alert("fieldValue"+fieldValue);
 
    
  };

/*my approach for callback is

    function myValidationAction21(fieldValue,callback) { // callback arg. here!!
 alert("i am execit");
 callback(fieldvalue);
 
    
  };
  
  var a=myValidationAction21("", function( responseFromFoo ) {
         return responseFromFoo;
       });
    alert("a==="+a);//give UNDEFINED 
*/  
 

 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
function myValidationAction2(fieldValue, callback) { // callback arg. here!!

  function foo() {   // (not here)
    var abc=null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {      // DETECT ALL 
      abc=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject) { // DETECT IE
      abc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    // SEND REQUEST TO SERVER
    abc.open("GET","ajax4.php?txt_email="+ fieldValue);
    abc.send();
    abc.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(abc.readyState==4) {
        callback( $(abc.responseText).text() );
      }
    };
  }

  foo();

}
```

and use like:

```
myValidationAction2("someFieldVal", function( responseFromFoo ) {
     console.dir( responseFromFoo );
});
```

Comment: how to call ? function please describe in detail

Comment: <input type="text" name="txt_mname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Middle Name"  id="txt_mname" data-bvalidator="required,alpha,minlen[5],myValidationAction2"> i call like this function